# Looping .to_csv Not Saving to Folders

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, text

I'm trying to get this loop to save multiple dataframes from csv files to individual txt files (using .to_csv) for data analysis. The csv files are across multiple folders in the same parent folder. I do have to join the dataframes with another fixed set of values, which is my "W_I0_df" dataframe, hence the second to last line.

```
W_I0_data_path = "C:/Users/.../W_L3_I0_000_exd.csv"
W_I0_df = pd.read_csv(W_I0_data_path, index_col=None, usecols=[3], names=['I0 Intensity (C/s)'], header=0)
W_dir_path = 'C:/Users/.../W'
folder_list = [src for src,_,_ in os.walk(W_dir_path)]

for subfolder in folder_list:
    subfolder_path = os.path.join(W_dir_path, subfolder)
    os.chdir(subfolder_path)
    for csv_files in glob.glob('/*.csv'):
        temp_df = pd.read_csv(csv_files, index_col=None, usecols=[2,3], names=['Energy (eV)', 'I1 Intensity (C/s)'], header=0)
        merge_df = temp_df.join(W_I0_df, on=None, how='left')
        merge_df.to_csv(csv_files+'.txt', index=False, header=False)
```

The code is executed without any issue. However, there are no txt files being written.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found that adding "subfolder_path" to glob.glob('/*.csv') before "'/*.csv'" fixes the problem. The code should instead be:

```
W_I0_data_path = "C:/Users/.../W_L3_I0_000_exd.csv"
W_I0_df = pd.read_csv(W_I0_data_path, index_col=None, usecols=[3], names=['I0 Intensity (C/s)'], header=0)
W_dir_path = 'C:/Users/.../W'
folder_list = [src for src,_,_ in os.walk(W_dir_path)]

for subfolder in folder_list:
    subfolder_path = os.path.join(W_dir_path, subfolder)
    os.chdir(subfolder_path)
    for csv_files in glob.glob(subfolder_path + '/*.csv'):
        temp_df = pd.read_csv(csv_files, index_col=None, usecols=[2,3], names=['Energy (eV)', 'I1 Intensity (C/s)'], header=0)
        merge_df = temp_df.join(W_I0_df, on=None, how='left')
        merge_df.to_csv(csv_files+'.txt', index=False, header=False)
```